# Descargar archivo de SoapClient

Tags: php, webservice

Utilizo la libreria nusoap_client de PHP para hacer consultas a un WSDL, este WSDL tiene un attachment en formato PDF que necesito descargar, ya intente el siguiente código

```
$response = $client->response;
$filename = "recibo";
$destination = dirname(__FILE__) . '/'.$filename.'.pdf';
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $response);
fclose($file);
```

Pero no me lo guarda correctamente, revise el WSDL con SOAP UI y si envia correctamente el PDF, conocen alguna otra manera de descargar dicho PDF.

Esto recibo del WSDL

```
%PDF-1.2
%���
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Page
/Parent 3 0 R
/Resources 4 0 R
/Contents 2 0 R
>> endobj
2 0 obj <>
```

Gracias.

Comment: Has verificado como viene la respuesta del WS, es probable que sea un arreglo u objeto y una de las claves sea ese fichero, y es posible que venga codificada en base64. puedes verificar con un `print_r($response);`

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar lo siguiente

```
file_put_contents($destination, $response);
```

Como lo hacen aquí
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42963585/parsing-raw-pdf-data-to-create-pdf-using-php, un aproximado de la respuesta que estás obteniendo del WS